# rvest - Scraping a Table

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

I am scraping a WebPage using rvest library, my, interest is to extract all the data from the table present in the webpage.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyr)

url <- ''

# Parsing the HTML Code from Website
hdb_webpage <- read_html(url)

## Grabbing Page Info - Table Input 1
dat_1 <- hdb_webpage %>%
  html_table(header=FALSE) %>% 
  .[[2]] %>%
  as.data.frame()
# Transposing
dat_1 <- as.data.frame(t(dat_1$X3))
# Changing colnames
colnames(dat_1) <- c("Name", "Address", "Category", "TradeType", "Contact")
```

I continue to do the same manually for the rest of the dataframes present in the list. There are actually 18 dataframe present in the list which consists of varying Variables and Observations, which leads to spending much time in cleaning the data.

Alternatively, for scraping the whole table, I use the following code;

```
tbls_ls <- hdb_webpage %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(header = FALSE) %>%
  .[2:18]

df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(tbls_ls), nrow=279, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df <- unique(df)
```

This code extracts all the information from the table into list and then I use *unlist* to convert into a dataframe and then apply *unique* to get relevant data.

Is there a way through which I can extract all the data from the table without going thorough one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the raw list `rw.list` read in from `html_table()` there are three `if`-cases to be handled differently.

```
library(rvest)

path <- 'https://services2.hdb.gov.sg/webapp/AA16RMSBusinessDirectory/AA16SLevelmap?SearchOption=1&BLK=166&STREET=WOODLANDS+STREET+13++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%EF%BF%BD&pcode=730166&STREETLIST=--&MAIN_TRADE_CODE=0000Please+Select+Category%24&Forward=&FROMHOME=true&Slvl=1&SEARCHPANEL=1&MAIN_TRADE_DESC'

# Parsing the HTML Code from Website
rw <- read_html(path)
rw.list <- html_table(rw)[-1]
names(rw.list) <- lapply(rw.list, function(x)  # attribute clean names
  unique(gsub("\\n|\\r|\\t|\\s+(More Information)?", "", x[1, ])))

l1 <- lapply(rw.list, function(x) t(x[-(1:2), ]))

l1 <- lapply(1:length(l1), function(x) {
  d <- as.data.frame(l[[x]], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  names(d) <- d[1, ]
  if (length(d) == 10 | length(d) == 6)
    out <- matrix(unlist(d[3, grep("Category|Trade|(Tel No)", names(d), )]), 
                  ncol=2,
                  dimnames=list(NULL, d[1, 1:2]))
  else if (length(d) == 8)
    out <- matrix(unlist(t(d[3, grep("Category|Trade|(Tel No)", names(d), )])), 
                  ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(NULL, d[1, 1:3]))
  else
    out <- d[3, ]
  return(cbind(id=names(l)[x], out))
})
```

The clean list we can merge with `Reduce()`.

```
result <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), l1)
```

***Result***

```
head(result, 3)
#                        id Category                                             Trade   Tel No
# 1   1.GREENEMERALDAQUARIA     Pets Aquarium Fish (freshwater/marine) And Accessories 68160208
# 2         2.SEEMRALICIOUS   Beauty                                      Beauty Salon 66357994
# 3 3.MORRISONOPTICALPTELTD Shopping                           Optical Goods & Eyewear 63666300
```